# What is the difference between the <%# and <%= opening tags?

Tags: .net, asp.net

While editing an aspx file I found both these opening tags used for seemingly the same thing. Is there a difference and if yes, what is it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`<%=` is a equivalent to `<% Repsonse.Write()`

You can write any content out here: for example

```
<%=myProperty + " additional Text" %>
```

`<%#` is a binding expression. You can retrieve any public value in the current context (for example in GridViews). But you cannot mix content here.

Take a look at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178366.aspx) for more information.

Comment: Ahh, I was wondering why <%= always caused my writes to be written out of sync with the output stream... Have been using labels instead. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is that the # symbol specifies a data binding directive, that is resolved at data binding time (for example, when you call Page.DataBind ) and the = sign specifies an evaluation expression just evaluates and prints to the HTML output when that line is processed.

Edit: Just adding that only inside <%# %> you have acces to databinding functions like Eval.

Answer (score 1):

<%= is shorthand for Response.Write().
<%# indicates that you're working with the data container in a data bound control.