# HtmlString vs. MvcHtmlString

Tags: .net-4.0, asp.net-mvc-3

`HtmlString` vs. `MvcHtmlString`

What are the differences bettween those two, or when to prefer one over the other?

**Edit:**

One thing to prefer `MvcHtmlString` over `HtmlString` is the extension method `IsNullOrEmpty` of `MvcHtmlString`.

Comment: Yes, good spot - I didn't realise HtmlString didn't have that.

Comment: Next to IsNullOrEmpty, it also has some other static methods (and one property) (PS: IsNullOrEmpty is not an extension method).

Answer (score 120, accepted):

`HtmlString` only exists in ASP.NET 4.

`MvcHtmlString` was a compatibility shim added to MVC 2 to support both .NET 3.5 and .NET 4. Now that MVC 3 is .NET 4 only, it's a fairly trivial subclass of `HtmlString` presumably for MVC 2->3 for source compatibility.

If you're ever going to drop back to MVC 2 it might make sense to use `IHtmlString` or `var` for values returned from MVC functions. Alternatively I think you can now just switch to `HtmlString` throughout.

Answer (score 21):

`HtmlString` was only introduced in .Net 4.0.

In ASP.Net 3.5 MVC 2.0, you should use `MvcHtmlString`.
In .Net 4.0, you should use `HtmlString`. (which is simpler)

Comment: The question is about asp.net-4 and MVC-3.

Answer (score 2):

MvcHtmlString is used to indicate when a string should not be re-encoded.

See [What is an MvcHtmlString and when should I use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2293357/what-is-an-mvchtmlstring-and-when-should-i-use-it)

and

[What does <%: %> do in ASP.NET (MVC2)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3331393/what-does-do-in-asp-net-mvc2/3331408#3331408)

Comment: So's HtmlString. Or anything that derives from IHtmlString.

Comment: *implements IHtmlString :) *pedant

Comment: Does not answer the OP question which is to know the difference between MvcHtmlString and HtmlString.