# ASP.NET MVC how to display html tags as html?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-2, tags

I display some text in the view:

```
....
 <%: model.Content %>
....
```

my model.Content contains html tags, and I want to display them not as text, but as html. How to do it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
<%= model.Content %>
```

Be careful with this because it could open your site to XSS attacks.

Answer (score 29):

As of MVC 3 you can use:

```
@Html.Raw(model.Content)
```

Answer (score 5):

Use:

```
<%: MvcHtmlString.Create(model.Content) %>
```

or

```
<%= model.Content %>
```

Because `<%:` does Html encoding, while `<%=` doesn't.

`MvcHtmlString.Create` creates a 'save' Html string, which`<%:` takes and prints out as is.

Comment: From http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3382860/htmlstring-vs-mvchtmlstring : In ASP.Net 3.5 MVC 2.0, you should use MvcHtmlString.
In .Net 4.0, you should use HtmlString. (which is simpler)

Answer (score 2):

```
<%= Model.Content %>
```

The colon : is short for Html.Encode() while equal = simply post what is in the string.