# HTML Encoding for HtmlHelper Extension Method

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, html-encode, html-helper

First of all I'm using MVC 3 RC1 with the Razor view engine. I've got an HTML helper extension which looks like this:

```
public static string TabbedMenuItem(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string text, string actionName, string controllerName) {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    builder.Append("<li>");

    builder.Append(text);

    builder.Append("</li>");
    return builder.ToString();
}
```

And on the view it's called like this:

```
@Html.TabbedMenuItem("Home", "Index", "Home")
```

The problem I've got is that MVC is automatically HTML encoding the result in the view so all I get is the encoded version of the string:

```
<li>Home</li>
```

Does anyone know how to disable the automatic encoding for your HTML helper extensions?

Thanks in advance
Andy

Comment: For future reference, MVC has a System.Web.Mvc.TagBuilder class that you might want to look into.  It doesn't negate the needs for returning IHtmlString, but it comes with more functionality than StringBuilder for this sort of task.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
public static IHtmlString TabbedMenuItem(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string text, string actionName, string controllerName)
{
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    builder.Append("<li>");

    builder.Append(text);

    builder.Append("</li>");
    return MvcHtmlString.Create(builder.ToString());
}
```

Use return value IHtmlString.
Hope this help.

Comment: Should this be `MvcHtmlString` or is that no longer the case in ASP.NET MVC 3?

Comment: @ehdv good question; I googled it and found (this)[http://stackoverflow.com/a/3382908/295686] (HtmlString is preferred in .NET 4+)

Answer (score 0):

Use [TagBuilder](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/views/using-the-tagbuilder-class-to-build-html-helpers-cs)