# What's the correct way to output HTML attributes / text with quotes in Razor / MVC3?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, razor

Lets say I have a function in my model, that generates a style tag based on an int

```
public string GetStyle(int? size){
    if(size > 99)
        return "style=\"margin: 20px;\"";
    else
        return "";
}
```

If I render this out using

```
<li @GetStyle(123)>123</li>
```

It outputs this:

```
<li style=""margin:20px;"">123</li>
```

(Note the double double-quotes). If I change the escaped double quotes in the function to *single* quotes, it outputs this:

```
<li style="'margin:20px;'">123</li>
```

Neither is correct, and I'm forced to either output an empty style tag if no style is required.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change your method so it returns a IHtmlString instead, something like this:

```
public IHtmlString GetStyle(int? size)
{
    if(size > 99)
        return new HtmlString("style=\"margin: 20px;\"");
    else
        return new HtmlString("");
}
```

Comment: You could use MVCHtmlString although that's only really for MVC2 -> MVC3, iHtmlString provides more future proofing. (HtmlString is .net 4) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3382860/htmlstring-vs-mvchtmlstring

Comment: How do you display the return IHtmlString result from GetStyle in view then? I tried it in MVC 5, it works for literal value, but does not work for the string retrieved from SQL Server, like new HtmlString(stringvaluefromdb);

Answer (score 0):

If you just omit the quotation marks around the value then they will be automatically added for you.

```
public string GetStyle(int? size){
    if(size > 99)
        return "style=margin:20px;";
    else
        return "";
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work if what your trying to achieve is something like `class="style1 style2"`