# @ statement in razor templates shows HTML symbols instead of quotes

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I've noted that `@` statement in Razor templates converts quotes in strings into HTML symbols.

How can I show correct HTML attribute then? Sample code:

```html
<body@(ViewBag.Highlight == true ? " onload=\"prettyPrint()\"" : "")>
```

result:

```html
 <body onload=&quot;prettyPrint()&quot;>
```

That's completely incorrect. How can i achieve normal:

```html
 <body onload="prettyPrint()">
```

in my case?

I've tried `HtmlString` object from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9665874/whats-the-correct-way-to-output-html-attributes-text-with-quotes-in-razor-m). But it's impossible to convert `HtmlString`  to `string` even with explicit type cast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to use `Html.Raw()`. Try it this way:

```
@Html.Raw(String.Format("<body{0}>", ViewBag.Highlight == true ? " onload=\"prettyPrint()\"" : ""))
```

As the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg480740%28v=vs.98%29.aspx) says:

> Returns markup that is not HTML encoded.

Comment: This way it works, thank you! One small correction: have to use `ViewBag.Highlight == true`, otherwise I get an error `Cannot convert null to 'bool' because it is a non-nullable value type`.