# Display an HTML Code like &reg or &copy in an Html.ActionLink Text

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, html.actionlink

unfortunately, I was not successful with my research for this topic.
With an anchor tag, I was able to do this:

```
<a href="..."> My Link &reg </a>
```

Now I want the same with an Html.Actionlink:

```
@Html.ActionLink("My Link &reg", "Action")
```

But the output is the same as the input and not a reg symbol as it is intended.
Any idea?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

```
@Html.ActionLink("My Link ®", "Action")
```

or

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Action")"> My Link &reg </a>
```

Comment: At the beginning I thought the same as your first suggestion but ain't it a bad code style if you see special characters in your code?

Answer (score 1):

ActionLink always use call of HttpUtility.Encode for the link text.

You can use UrlHelper Method like

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Action")">My Link &reg</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use an [`HtmlString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.htmlstring.htmlstring.aspx) (`MvcHtmlString` in [.NET 2 / MVC 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3382860/htmlstring-vs-mvchtmlstring)) to indicate that you do not wish it to be re-encoded:

```
@Html.ActionLink(new HtmlString("My Link &reg"), "Action");
```

Comment: Looks right, but Html.ActionLink does not accept HtmlString as an input type (it has to be string, not HtmlString)

Comment: Damn, though it shouldn't be difficult to whip up an overloaded extension method that does.

Comment: Ignore my previous comment. Went ahead and implemented this. See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14488497/1015595

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I solved this in MVC 2:

```
/// <summary>
/// Creates an anchor tag based on the passed in controller type and method.
/// Does NOT encode passed in link text.
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="TController">The controller type</typeparam>
/// <param name="htmlHelper">The HTML helper</param>
/// <param name="action">The method to route to</param>
/// <param name="linkText">The linked text to appear on the page</param>
/// <returns>A formatted anchor tag</returns>
public static MvcHtmlString ActionLink<TController>( this HtmlHelper htmlHelper,
                                                     Expression<Action<TController>> action,
                                                     HtmlString linkText ) where TController : Controller
{
    return ActionLink( htmlHelper, action, linkText, null, null );
}

/// <summary>
/// Creates an anchor tag based on the passed in controller type and method.
/// Does NOT encode passed in link text.
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="TController">The controller type</typeparam>
/// <param name="htmlHelper">The HTML helper</param>
/// <param name="action">The method to route to</param>
/// <param name="linkText">The linked text to appear on the page</param>
/// <param name="routeValues">The route values</param>
/// <param name="htmlAttributes">The HTML attributes</param>
/// <returns>A formatted anchor tag</returns>
public static MvcHtmlString ActionLink<TController>( this HtmlHelper htmlHelper,
                                                     Expression<Action<TController>> action,
                                                     HtmlString linkText,
                                                     object routeValues,
                                                     object htmlAttributes ) where TController : Controller
{
    var routingValues = GetRouteValuesFromExpression( action, routeValues );

    var url = UrlHelper.GenerateUrl( null, //routeName
                                     null, //actionName
                                     null, //controllerName
                                     routingValues,
                                     htmlHelper.RouteCollection,
                                     htmlHelper.ViewContext.RequestContext,
                                     false ); //includeImplicitMvcValues

    var tagBuilder = new TagBuilder("a")
        { 
            InnerHtml = !String.IsNullOrEmpty( linkText.ToString() ) ? linkText.ToString() : String.Empty
        };

    tagBuilder.MergeAttributes( (IDictionary<string, object>)htmlAttributes );
    tagBuilder.MergeAttribute( "href", url );

    return MvcHtmlString.Create( tagBuilder.ToString( TagRenderMode.Normal ) );
}
```

It is strongly typed, as in the MVC futures NuGet package. So you can use it like this:

```
<%= Html.ActionLink<HomeController>( x => x.Index(),
                                     new HtmlString( "Don't Encode Me!<sup>&reg;</sup>" ) ) %>
```