# ServiceStack Razor Templating and IHtmlString in .net 4

Tags: servicestack

I am trying to get ServiceStack.Razor and [htmltags](https://github.com/darthfubumvc/htmltags) to play nicely together.
It looks like I need the [TemplateBase](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.Razor/Templating/TemplateBase.cs#L220) to check for IHtmlString when writing out the page. The code below works (and takes its cues from [MvcHtmlString/DynamicMvcHtmlString](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack/Html/TagBuilder.cs#L60)) but this doesn't seem like a great solution because the reflection will happen with every write.

Any ideas?

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Writes the specified object to the template result.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="object">The object to write.</param>
    public void Write(object @object)
    {
        if (@object == null)
            return;

        if (@object is MvcHtmlString)
        {
            Builder.Append(@object);
        }
        else if (typeof (HttpContext).Assembly.GetType("System.Web.IHtmlString") != null && (typeof (HttpContext).Assembly.GetType("System.Web.IHtmlString")).IsInstanceOfType(@object))
        {
            Builder.Append(@object);
        }
        else
        {
            var strValue = Convert.ToString(@object);
            Builder.Append(HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(strValue));
        }
    }
```

My current workaround is to wrap the html in a new MvcHtmlString

```
    public static MvcHtmlString ToMvcHtmlString(this HtmlTag htmlTag)
    {
        return MvcHtmlString.Create(htmlTag.ToHtmlString());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using ASP.Net 4 then you should be able to reference `IHtmlString` directly:

```
var hs = @object as IHtmlString;
if (hs != null)
{
    Builder.Append(hs);
}
```

The problem is if you're on the older ASP.Net but want to use MVC 2 - there Microsoft came up with the [slightly awkward cludge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3382860/htmlstring-vs-mvchtmlstring) of `MvcHtmlString`, a class that's treated like it implements `System.Web.IHtmlString` but actually can't because MVC 2 is compiled against the previous version of `System.Web` (which didn't have `IHtmlString`).

Now MVC 3 and above *require* ASP.Net 4, so this isn't a problem any more, just always use `IHtmlString`.

If you're stuck with MVC 2 and .Net 3.5 then your current workaround is the only fix.

However, as you're using .Net 4 you don't need to stick with an MVC 2 project - [you should be able to upgrade to MVC 3 with minimal changes](http://www.asp.net/whitepapers/mvc3-release-notes#upgrading).