# Custom Helper is not working correctly

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have created the following Html Helper Class for displaying a Image:

**Class:**

```
namespace MvcWebMobile.CustomHelpers
{
    public static class CustomHelper
    {
        public static string Image(this HtmlHelper helper, string id, string url, string alternateText)
        {
            return Image(helper, id, url, alternateText, null);
        }

        public static string Image(this HtmlHelper helper, string id, string url, string alternateText, object htmlAttributes)
        {
            // Create tag builder
            var builder = new TagBuilder("img");

            // Create valid id
            builder.GenerateId(id);

            // Add attributes
            builder.MergeAttribute("src", url);
            builder.MergeAttribute("alt", alternateText);
            builder.MergeAttributes(new RouteValueDictionary(htmlAttributes));

            // Render tag
            return builder.ToString(TagRenderMode.SelfClosing);
        }
    }
}
```

**View:**

```
@Html.Image("img1", "../../Content/images/icons-18-black.png", "logo")
```

Now when i use the custom helper in my view the Image is not displayed, instead of image following message is printed on web page

```
<img alt="logo" id="img1" src="../../Content/images/icons-18-black.png" /> <img alt="logo" border="4px" id="img1" src="../../Content/images/icons-18-black.png" />
```

Comment: why don't u pass app relative path of image ?

Comment: "~/Content/images/icons-18-black.png"

Comment: I tried but it is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your helper should return a `HtmlString` instead of a `string`.

```
public static HtmlString Image(this HtmlHelper helper, string id, string url, string alternateText)
{
    return Image(helper, id, url, alternateText, null);
}

public static HtmlString Image(this HtmlHelper helper, string id, string url, string alternateText, object htmlAttributes)
{
    // ...
    return new HtmlString(builder.ToString(TagRenderMode.SelfClosing));
}
```

Comment: why we shouldn't use mvcHtmlString?

Comment: My comment is a link, click it. It works too, but in the future it may become deprecated, there's no reason to use it instead of `HtmlString`.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of returning string try returning `MvcHtmlString`,

```
 public static MvcHtmlString Image(this HtmlHelper helper, string id, string url, string alternateText)
 {

 }
```

Comment: [You shouldn't use `MvcHtmlString` in MVC 3 and up.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3382908/247702)

Answer (score 1):

Use MvchtmlString:

```
public static MvcHtmlString Image(this HtmlHelper helper, string id, string url, string alternateText)
 {
// ...
    return new MvcHtmlString(builder.ToString(TagRenderMode.SelfClosing));
 }
```