# What's the difference between <%: and <%= and <%# in aspx?

Tags: asp.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the difference between <%# %> and <%= %>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/160097/whats-the-difference-between-and)
>   [<%$, <%@, <%=, <%# … what's the deal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/957284/whats-the-deal)

I apologise if this is duplicated, but it's infuriatingly difficult to google for.

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/197047/what-is-the-difference-between-and

Comment: and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/160097/whats-the-difference-between-and and several others

Comment: Cheers, shame you can't search for <% using the search... even the suggestions list didn't have those in. How on earth did you find them? :) I'll close as dupe

Comment: Visit the questions above that this one duplicates and upvote it. Comment if it helps you at all. Adding a comment might help nudge it up the results list in your favorite search engine.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`<%:` is new to .NET 4.0 - it is equivalent to `Response.Write(HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(...))`.

`<%=` is older and stands for `Response.Write(...)` only.

`<%#` is a [binding expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178366.aspx).

Answer (score 8):

[Here's](http://weblogs.asp.net/ahmedmoosa/archive/2010/10/06/embedded-code-and-inline-server-tags.aspx) a good article on them. In summary:

Page Directive

```
<%@ Page Language="C#"  %>
```

Rendering Code

```
<% Response.Write("Hello World!");  %>

<%= SayHello("Ahmed") %>

<%: DateTime.Now.ToString()  %>
```

Expression Syntax

```
<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnStrFromWebConfig  %>

<%$ AppSettings:ValueFromWebConfig  %>

<%$ Resources:Resource, Arabic  %>

<%$ RouteValue:year  %>

<%$ YourExpressionPrefix : Any   %>
```

Data Binding  Syntax

```
<%# Eval("Name")  %>

<%# Bind("Name")  %>

<%# XPath ("Name")  %>
```

Comment Server

```
<%-- <asp:Label runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>-- %>
```