# Tags in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

What's the difference between `<%= Something %>` and `<%# Something %>`?

Are there any other modifiers of this kind?

#### Duplicate

> [What is the difference between the <%# and <%= opening tags?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100853/what-is-the-difference-between-the-and-opening-tags)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See these questions:

- [What is the difference between the <%# and <%= opening tags?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100853/what-is-the-difference-between-the-and-opening-tags)
- [In ASP.NET what are the differant ways to inline code in the .aspx?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28219/in-asp-net-what-are-the-differant-ways-to-inline-code-in-the-aspx)